# Netty - how to detect / extract contents of posts?

Tags: java, json, http, netty

I am using Netty 5.0 and still new to its http functions.
I need to communicate between a Netty server and a JavaScript app via json strings.

The server handler is very simple as the following code:

```
public class HttpServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {
    @Override
    protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

The Initializer code:

```
public class NettyHttpServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new HttpServerHandler());
   }
}
```

Whenever the client sends a json string via post method, the server prints out:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 51
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8888
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */ *
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyWebApp02.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

{"cmd":"he", "ver":1, "dvt":3}
```

What I need is only the last line, the json string. However the server received input as multi strings and I cannot cast them to high structures (such as `HttpRequest`) to get that content. I can parse / check all strings to detect json strings but look likes it is the worst way. I have tried to improve the code (such as using `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest>`, removing `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder`) but has no luck so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a Webserver, you should use [`HttpServerCodec`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpServerCodec.html) in combination with optionally a [`HttpObjectAggregator`](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpObjectAggregator.html).

Your `ChannelInitializer` should look like the following:

```java
public class NettyHttpServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("http", new HttpServerCodec());

        // optional, makes life easier
        pipeline.addLast("dechunker", new HttpObjectAggregator(65536)); 

        pipeline.addLast("handler", new HttpServerHandler());
   }
}
```

Your handler would then handle `FullHttpRequest` if `HttpObjectAggregator` is present, or different kind of `HttpRequest` messages (this is harder, see [this](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopServerHandler.html) example).

I will be focussing my answer mainly on that we receive [`FullHttpRequest`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/FullHttpRequest.html).

When receiving a `FullHttpRequest`, there are a few things that we can do:

- Get the uri using `request.getUri()`
- Get the HTTP method used by `request.getMethod()`
- Get the headers using `request.headers()`
- Get the contents of a POST/PUT request by using `request.content()`

To answer your question, you should first call `request.getMethod()` to check if the method is POST or PUT, then call `request.content()` to get the contents.

Example:

```java
public class HttpServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {
    @Override
    protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest msg) throws Exception {
        if(msg.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.POST) || msg.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.PUT)) {
            System.out.println(msg.content().toString(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for very fast answer and for your code. It works like a charm!!!

(just a tiny change for someone who needs (original one may run well on other systems but bit problem on mine):  change the line if(msg.getMethod().equals("POST") || msg.getMethod().equals("GET")) into if(msg.getMethod().toString().equals("POST") || msg.getMethod().toString().equals("GET") )

Comment: @Tony I have updated the code to make it compare with [HttpMethod.GET](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpMethod.html) instead of comparing it with a string, it was indeed a bug.